# Как добавить данные в таблицу БД (SQL Server ) на C# (WPF )

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

У меня есть обработчик кнопки при нажатие на которую в таблицу **Должности** должны добавляться значения. Я в `sqlСommand` засунул запрос, но как теперь этот запрос выполнить при нажатие на кнопку ?

````
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace EzApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string connectionString;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            connectionString = "Data Source=HOME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=srvr;Integrated Security=True"; 

        }


        

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCnct = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCnct.Open();

            if (sqlCnct.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ez");
            }

        }

        private void InsertClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Должности (кодДолжности, названиеДолжности) VALUES (62, 'зам начальника')");
           

        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: Почитайте пожалуйста базовую документацию/мануалы по тем методам и классам, которые вы используете, вы ведь спрашиваете базовые вещи, которые написаны в самом начале любого "мануала". К примеру, [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonetcore/2.4.php), ну или [вот](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/executing-a-command).

Comment: ```private void InsertClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Должности (кодДолжности, названиеДолжности) VALUES (12, 'GG')", sqlCnct);

     MessageBox.Show(command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());

 }```
Почему после нажатия на кнопку InsertClick в таблицу не добавились данные?